# How is this SAS dataset being emptied?

Tags: sas

Running SAS 9.3 supporting MXG 32.10 on Windows

I have a dataset, WORK.SMFLISTD, which has 15 obs.  At the end of processing, it has 0 obs even though I can find no modification to it.  I can find no reference to WORK.SMFLISTD between these two states.  Searches for SMFLISTD in SASLOG find no reference to it.  Searches for WORK find many DATASETS DELETE statements but none reference SMFLISTD.  There is no overall DATASETS KILL for the WORK library.  In any case, if there were, SMFLISTD still exists but with 0 obs.  Given these conditions, how does this dataset end up empty?

Options are:

```
options source source2 symbolgen mprint;
```

At the beginning of the run:

```
77         data work.smflistd(keep=refdate dsname volser);
78           set
78       ! work.smflist(obs=&getcnt);
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable GETCNT resolves to 15
79         run;

NOTE: There were 15 observations read from the data set WORK.SMFLIST.
NOTE: The data set WORK.SMFLISTD has 15 observations and 3 variables.
```

At the end of the run:

```
MPRINT(RUNCICSSMF):   proc print data=work.smflistd;
MPRINT(RUNCICSSMF):   title "SMFLISTD After";
NOTE: No observations in data set WORK.SMFLISTD.

MPRINT(RUNCICSSMF):   data daily.smflist;
MPRINT(RUNCICSSMF):   set work.smflistd;
MPRINT(RUNCICSSMF):   modify daily.smflist key=dsnid;
MPRINT(RUNCICSSMF):   procdt = datetime();
MPRINT(RUNCICSSMF):   run;
3223                                     The SAS System        06:41 Wednesday, November 12, 2014


NOTE: There were 0 observations read from the data set WORK.SMFLISTD.
NOTE: The data set DAILY.SMFLIST has been updated.  There were 0 observations rewritten, 0 
      observations added and 0 observations deleted.
```

Comment: Without the rest of the code it's difficult to say.

Comment: The rest of the code is 70,000 lines, expanded...  I'd be glad to answer questions.  Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to a table in SAS via shorthand notation, ie SMFLIS: will hit all tables that start with SMFLIS, try searching for something like that in your delete statements. Though if the table was deleted it wouldn't say 0 obs would say not found or something else instead.

Comment: The question as asked is off topic, because you don't include the code needed for us to figure it out.  If that's infeasible/impossible due to length, this may simply be a question not appropriate for here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Robert says, there are many possibilities.  One "gotcha" is the global obs setting:

```
options obs=0;
```

You could check for this..

Comment: Certainly, in the end this was it.  One of the %include expansions sets obs=0 and then obs=max later.  At one point, it leaves obs=0 and ends up exiting that way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are a multitude of ways that this could be happening so searching for a reference to the table may not work.

You can run the code to the point where the table is created.  Open the table (so that it is locked), and then finish running the rest of the code.  Because the table is locked, the step that tries to empty it will fail and show in the log as either an `ERROR:` or a `WARNING:`.